# Button not showing in the emulator when i run the Codenameone program

Tags: java, codenameone

[image]

I pasted the program to make a button from codenameone developer guide and i used the code in netbeans but when i click run it shows nothing in emulator

Comment: Please post your code in text, not as a picture. This makes it hard for us to help you out. Also, I notice some red text on that screen, so I guess that might give you some information as well.

Comment: that red text always show when i run codenameone in both eclipse and netbeans

Answer (score 0):

You removed the `hi.show();` call. Without that no Form will show and the app won't start.

The red text is related to your java installation and is a JDK bug on Windows unrelated to us. You can google that text to see suggested workarounds.